# How can I have a different background color for each marquee?

Tags: javascript, jquery, marquee

Ive been asked by a client to use  in a page template and the client have asked if its possible to change the background colour of the marquee per marquee so when marquee 1 ends its starts marquee 2 but uses background xxx then when that ends it starts marquee 3 with background xxx,

I've seen javascript been used with on with marquee but not a decent example, any ideas on how to achieve such a task, this is what I have so far:

```
<marquee id="marquee1" onfinish="switch_marque();">Test Run 1</marquee>
<marquee id="marquee2" onfinish="switch_marque();">Test Run 2</marquee>
<marquee id="marquee3" onfinish="switch_marque();">Test Run 3</marquee>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $( document ).ready(function() {
       function switch_marquee(){
           $(this).css("background-color","green"); 
       };
   )};
</script>
```

Comment: Move the `switch_marquee()` out of the `ready()` callback

Comment: Do you want to assign random colors or your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `switch_marque()` function shouldn't be inside the `$(document).ready()` as it will only be called when the marquees are loaded.

Before I continue:

**`Marquee` is considered an OBSOLETE feature of HTML5! Browsers might drop support in the future. Try to avoid it and use CSS solutions instead!**

([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee))

```
<marquee id="marquee1" onfinish="switch_marque(1);">Test Run 1</marquee>
<marquee id="marquee2" onfinish="switch_marque(2);">Test Run 2</marquee>
<marquee id="marquee3" onfinish="switch_marque(3);">Test Run 3</marquee>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function switch_marquee(value){

       var nextMarquee = (value++)%3;
       $("#marquee" + nextMarquee).css("background-color","green"); 
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your solution but it just outputs 3 marquees running at the same time and when it goes to the end it doesn't finish it just carries on around the page, see my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lnsvn4xk/

Answer (score 1):

Extending @Jordumus's answer with random Background-color example:

```
<marquee id="marquee1" onfinish="switch_marque(1);">Test Run 1</marquee>
<marquee id="marquee2" onfinish="switch_marque(2);">Test Run 2</marquee>
<marquee id="marquee3" onfinish="switch_marque(3);">Test Run 3</marquee>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function switch_marquee(value){

       var nextMarquee = (value++)%3;
       $("#marquee" + nextMarquee).css("background-color", getRandomColor()); 

    };

    // custom function to generate and return random color;
    function getRandomColor() {
       var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
       var color = '#';
       for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
           color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
       }
       return color;
    }

</script>
```

> Don't bite me, I've just tried to help him using random colors :)

Answer (score 0):

In your function:

```
function switch_marquee(){
               $(this).css("background-color","green"); 
           };
```

`this` references to the `window` context, not the `marquee` elements, you have to bind the function to use the element `marquee` as a context you can do this:

```
<marquee id="marquee1" onfinish="switch_marque.bind(this); switch_marque()">Test Run 1</marquee>
```

Or, I´d rather do this way:

```
<marquee id="marquee1">Test Run 1</marquee>
<marquee id="marquee2">Test Run 2</marquee>
<marquee id="marquee3">Test Run 3</marquee>

$("marquee").on('finish', function(){

 $(this).css("backgroundColor","green");

});
```